# How to set axis ranges with density plot in CairoMakie?

Tags: julia, makie.jl

**Is it possible to fix the range of x and y axis in a density plot with CairoMakie ?**

For an example, I would like to fix the range of x axis from 10 to 100 and force the y axis to start from 0 (I want to remove the gap above the major x axis)

```
fig = CairoMakie.density(ages_obtention, color = (:blue, 0.3),
    strokecolor = :blue, strokewidth = 2, strokearound = true,
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xlims!` and `ylims!`

```
fig = CairoMakie.density(ages_obtention, color = (:blue, 0.3),
    strokecolor = :blue, strokewidth = 2, strokearound = true,
)
xlims!(fig.axis, (10, 100))
ylims!(fig.axis, (0, nothing))

fig
```